# Why navigation sounds from Bluetooth are not working while in radio mode?

Tags: audio, corolla, bluetooth

My specific issues is with Toyota Corolla SUN FL6 2016 model.

While in radio mode, it can not be overridden by sounds from Bluetooth such navigation directions from Waze. I tried with many phone models and also noticed this on few other car models.

If I want navigation, I need to switch to Bluetooth mode, but then I can't hear radio.

I know that this is not an intrinsic limitation because when I have incoming calls, I do hear the call sound and can answer and hear the other person, all through BT while in radio mode.

Am I missing some configuration on my phone or in the cars media system?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! This seems like normal operation to me. My 2018 Silverado does the same thing. If I want to hear the navigation, I have to put it in media mode, then stream whatever audio I want to hear from my phone. When in this mode, the navigation will override the audio and I'm safely on my way.

Comment: @Paulster2 It sounds like normal operation to me as well but I was hoping that this can be configured somehow to work with radio as well.

Comment: I don't think you can, unless you were to rewrite the code in the operating system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know that this is not an intrinsic limitation because when I have incoming calls, I do hear the call sound and can answer and hear the other person, all through BT while in radio mode.

This isn't quite as simple as you'd think - BT for *phone* and BT for *media* playback are actually different profiles in the protocol and there's quite alot of differences under the hood so to speak. So when a call comes in the phone uses the BT connection to send a message telling the car "Hey I've got an incoming call!" and that's what lets the media system know it needs to go from radio to "phone" mode. Navigation prompts such as those from Waze don't have an equivilant, it's all just so much streaming audio as far as a connected BT audio device is concerned, which is why the car doesn't know to interrupt the the radio playback.

Sure Toyota *could* program the media system such that if incoming audio were detected on the BT connection that it automatically switched, but you'd find that would be sub-optimal as it can only *react* not predict, so you'd lose a fraction of the start of the announcement and automatically switching back is trickier because again it's a "dumb" audio stream - how do you know it's finished giving the instructions rather than just paused? So they could spend the time and effort to develop a not-especially-great solution, that would probably act as a further disincentive for customers to spend money with them to get the on-board navigation option, which of course would give you exactly the behavior you're looking for.

Answer (score -1):

One guess why navigation prompts are heard when attempting to listen to the radio - programming. While you may consider multitasking is easy, using navigation and radio simultaneously effectively interferes with each other within the same unit so its simply not programmed to allow it. While it may seem intuitive to have the radio blasting while using navigation to 'talk' you thru your selected route, it's simply not programmed to do so. The only way to have your cake and eat it is to have thousands or millions demanding it before manufacturers consider updating programming. As it is, most up to date radios allow mating cellphones to ring thru the radio and open the phone so hands free driving is safer while automatically muting music. Unfortunately, distracted driving still occurs with many not capable of separating driving duties from being distracted by radio, cellphone and navigation.